# How to add the Signed-off-by field in the git patch

Tags: git

I'm generating a git patch. And then I want to send it to the project maintainer.

I want to mark my Name and my email address as `signed-off-by` in the git patch

How to do it? in order that the project maintainer get the `signed-off-by` field with my name and email address.

Comment: `man git-format-patch<cr>/sign` =)

Comment: Don't forget to understand what exactly you are signing for: a DCO (Developer Certificate of Origin): http://stackoverflow.com/a/35238070/6309

Answer (score 85, accepted):

When you commit, just use:

```
git commit -s
```

or

```
git commit --signoff
```

Or you can just write at the end of the commit message, on a line by itself separated by a blank line from the body of the commit:

```
Signed-off-by: Your Name <your.email@example.com>
```

If you already have the commit, use `git commit -s --amend` to add the above signoff line.

Or, if you are going to be sending this as a patch or patch series, you can use `git format-patch -s` or `--signoff` to add the signoff to the patch itself, without modifying the commit.

Answer (score 2):

use `git commit -s --amend` for amending with the last commit or use `git commit -s` to current ongoing commit. It will add `Signed-off-by: YourGitConfigName <YourGitConfigEmail>` ad the end of the commit message.