# git add Signed-off-by line using format.signoff not working

Tags: git, format, config

My client git version is 1.7.0.4.

I want to automatically add a "Signed-off-by" line for the committer at the end of the commit log message when commit a message.

1. When I set `git config --global format.signoff true`, and run `git commit -m "modify something"`, I see no "Signed-off-by" in `git log`.
2. If I use `git commit -m -s  "modify something"`, then "Signed-off-by" does show in `git log`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update for Git 2.14.x/2.15: as I mentioned in "[Git - Detect if commit is signed off programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41361273/6309)", you will be able to parse a commit message trailer for `Signed-off-By` line.

> "`git interpret-trailers`" has been taught a "`--parse`" and a few other options to make it easier for scripts to grab existing trailer lines from a commit log message.

See [stefanct](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1905491/stefanct)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536244/6309) for [`commit-msg` client-side hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_commit_msg) which would use `git interpret-trailers`.

---

Original answer (2013)

`format.signoff` is [about patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962112/6309) (as illustrated, for instance, [in this patch](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg133426.html)):

```
format.signoff
```

> A boolean value which lets you enable the -s/--signoff option of **[`format-patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)** by default

It has no bearing on `git commit -s`.

In other words, you don't have to signoff every commit, but when you are publishing them as patch for others to use (as in "[git: submitting patches](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/SubmittingPatches;hb=HEAD)"), *then* you should sign them.

For the exact signification of `Signed-of-by`, see "[What is the Sign Off feature in Git for?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35238070/6309)".

Answer (score 50):

There is now an easy way to automatically sign-off any commit that is not already signed-off by using hooks and the `git-interpret-trailers` command. In the upcoming version 2.15 of git the command allows to trivially check for an existing sign-off (no matter what's its value/author is) and add yours if there is non yet. As of October 2017 the required code is **not** in any git release yet (but in its `master` branch)!

Save the following as `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` or `.git/hooks/commit-msg` (see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) for the differences) and make it executable.

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME=$(git config user.name)
EMAIL=$(git config user.email)

if [ -z "$NAME" ]; then
    echo "empty git config user.name"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$EMAIL" ]; then
    echo "empty git config user.email"
    exit 1
fi

git interpret-trailers --if-exists doNothing --trailer \
    "Signed-off-by: $NAME <$EMAIL>" \
    --in-place "$1"
```

Comment: Nicely done. +1. I reference your answer in mine for more visibility, and reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/41361273/6309 where I mentioned `git interpret-trailers`.

Comment: Thanks for proposing a solution based on this `git-interpret-trailers` technique. To me, the decisive advantage is that this works regardless of the tool triggering the commit and how it's configured -- I often do that with `git gui`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not always the case. I can't remember exactly which but I had some application that worked around this (one can do similarly with `git commit -n`) and committed directly w/o executing the hook.

Comment: If you are on a newer version of git (I am on 2.25.x), `<your-repo>/.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample` comes with the code for sign-off (it's commented). You need to `cp prepare-commit-msg.sample prepare-commit-msg` and uncomment the line that starts with `SOB=$(git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT...` and the line after that. Make the file executable using `chmod +x <your-repo>/.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 25):

You can signoff by default in a project by creating a file (say "~/MYPROJECT/git-template") that contains some blank lines and the signed-off-by text like this:

```
Signed-off-by: Your Name <your.email@example.com>
```

Then configure git to use that as a commit template.  For example:

```
git config commit.template ~/MYPROJECT/git-template
```

Make sure your project *documents* somewhere what signed-off-by means for the project.  Here's some text you can copy into your CONTRIBUTING.md file:

> All contributions (including pull requests) must agree to the
>   Developer Certificate of Origin (DCO) version 1.1. This
>   is exactly the same one created and used by the Linux kernel
>   developers and posted on http://developercertificate.org/. This is a
>   developer's certification that he or she has the right to submit the
>   patch for inclusion into the project. Simply submitting a contribution
>   implies this agreement, however, please include a "Signed-off-by" tag
>   in every patch (this tag is a conventional way to confirm that you
>   agree to the DCO).

Answer (score 3):

To automatically add the `--signoff/-s` option to all commits you make in a git repository:

```
cd <REPO>
cp .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
edit .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
```

Then uncomment the last block of code:

```
SOB=$(git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT | sed -n 's/^\(.*>\).*$/Signed-off-by: \1/p')
git interpret-trailers --in-place --trailer "$SOB" "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"
if test -z "$COMMIT_SOURCE"
  then
    /usr/bin/perl -i.bak -pe 'print "\n" if !$first_line++' "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"
fi
```