# Git - Detect if commit is signed off

Tags: git

Is there any git command or easier format to determine if a commit is or isn't signed off?

Answer (score 22):

With [Git 1.7.9, Oct. 2011](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c37f1fce6cb7997dbb2703d35eef0dfd86c5070), you how `git log --show-signature` (mentioned in [Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22237/kris)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57710011/6309)), but [with 2.10 (Q3 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34019622/6309), you can simply set `git config log.showSignature true`, which will work with `git-log`, `git-show`, `git-whatchanged` and `git-reflog`.

---

To facilitate grepping "`Signed-off-By`", you now (Git 2.12, Q1 2017) can log with only the "trailer" part of the commit message. (The trailer includes the "`Signed-off-By`" and other "`Acknowledged By`" messages)

See [commit b1d31c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b1d31c8954f9c21b275f4fb7d872414b564c201c), [commit d9f31fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9f31fbfe98e0e363a3c69aaf6badecc746afe6b) (19 Nov 2016) by [Jacob Keller (`jacob-keller`)](https://github.com/jacob-keller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f008159](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f008159fc2dec7b98e74736751d3e6ad8d9c060f), 19 Dec 2016, Git 2.12.0-rc0)</sup>

> ### `pretty`: add `%(trailers)` format for displaying trailers of a commit message

In addition to `%(subject)`, `%(body)`, "`git log --pretty=format:...`"
learned a new placeholder `%(trailers)` and `%(contents:trailers)`.

---

You also have **[`git interpret-trailers`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers)**, which has just evolved in Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017)

See [commit 5a0d0c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a0d0c037cc187a6eee6329206b9f6a48746a054) (20 Aug 2017) by [Martin Ågren (``)](https://github.com/).
See [commit 58311c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58311c66fd316dff8f2c68a634ca0cf968227870), [commit cc1735c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc1735c4a3cf3377289640ce1af6b4c4523bee11), [commit a388b10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a388b10fc17c435df32c3875225a1468edad9535), [commit 99e09da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99e09dafd7b7bcac4d8189b41dc6038bf36334f5), [commit 0000239](https://github.com/git/git/commit/000023961a0c02d6e21dc51ea3484ff71abf1c74), [commit fdbdb64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fdbdb64f49959f9c83329554080934895f02ae59), [commit 56c493e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56c493ed1b9c067813fb95ff7cd4f69c7c1d2e36) (15 Aug 2017), and [commit 8abc898](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8abc89800c09cda7910c2211ebbbbb95a3008b63) (10 Aug 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 06cf4f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06cf4f2d87d670f6d49c208fa41933941205da90), 27 Aug 2017)</sup>

> "`git interpret-trailers`" has been taught a ["`--parse`" and a few
> other options](https://github.com/git/git/blob/06cf4f2d87d670f6d49c208fa41933941205da90/Documentation/git-interpret-trailers.txt#L109-L123) to make it easier for scripts to grab existing
> trailer lines from a commit log message.

```
git log --pretty=format:%(trailers:only:unfold)
```

Actually:

```
git log --pretty=format:%(trailers:only,unfold)
                                     ^^^^^
```

See [commit 84ff053](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84ff053d47c20c9f417f857e4adac0bcd8e01f0d) (01 Oct 2017) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 436b359](https://github.com/git/git/commit/436b35942cb5198a8d5e915690e65ee1c860baf2), 07 Oct 2017)</sup>

> ### `pretty.c`: delimit "`%(trailers)`" arguments with "`,`"

> In preparation for adding consistent "`%(trailers)`" atom options to
> `git-for-each-ref(1)`'s "`--format`" argument, change "`%(trailers)`" in
> `pretty.c` to separate sub-arguments with a "`,`", instead of a "`:`".
>
> Multiple sub-arguments are given either as "`%(trailers:unfold,only)`" or
> "`%(trailers:only,unfold)`".
>
> This change disambiguates between "top-level" arguments, and arguments
> given to the trailers atom itself. It is consistent with the behavior of
> "`%(upstream)`" and "`%(push)`" atoms.

---

Note: this is more robust with Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), since "`git interpret-trailers`" and its underlying machinery had a buggy code that attempted to ignore patch text after commit log message, which triggered in various codepaths that will always get the log message alone and never get such an input.

See [commit 66e83d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66e83d9b41f7438cb167b9bb54093ebbf0532437), [commit ffce7f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffce7f590fabee6f2314ffd891f1fd3629222839), [commit e5fba5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5fba5d55886eaf48aeeb158dd4d30c2fc0294c9), [commit 1688c9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1688c9a4894df517241026c7a3848bdc84607986), [commit c188668](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c188668e387509565237a865a1c63e890f6bbcd7), [commit 00a21f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00a21f5cbda35eb5d355b453849b625eeca7eac4), [commit a3b636e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3b636e21574e6cff1494e0a84644e06201ddb8d), [commit 0d2db00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d2db00e24ee2df4459151c5ba6de9306e30e727) (23 Aug 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fba9654](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fba9654364a523bf146df26052ab05dd52c1d719), 17 Sep 2018)</sup>

> ### `sequencer`: ignore "`---`" divider when parsing trailers

> When the sequencer code appends a signoff or cherry-pick origin, it uses the default trailer-parsing options, which treat "`---`" as the end of the commit message.
> As a result, it may be fooled by a commit message that contains that string and fail to find the existing trailer block. Even more confusing, the actual append code does not know about "`---`", and always appends to the end of the string.
> This can lead to bizarre results.
>
> E.g., appending a signoff to a commit message like this:
>
> ```
>  subject
>
>  body
>  ---
>  these dashes confuse the parser!
>
>  Signed-off-by: A
> ```
>
> results in output with a final block like:
>
> ```
>  Signed-off-by: A
>
>  Signed-off-by: A
> ```
>
> The parser thinks the final line of the message is "body", and ignores everything else, claiming there are no trailers.
> So we output an extra newline separator (wrong) and add a duplicate signoff (also wrong).
>
> Since we know we are feeding a pure commit message, we can simply tell the parser to ignore the "`---`" divider.

---

Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) adds several options:

See [commit 0b691d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b691d8685131c2c10e1a2cf2acc9b8920c5365f), [commit fd2015b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd2015b323d283c73346d70d2285a927650bb60a), [commit d9b936d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9b936db5226ed4b87d42a2c91324adc50c768b6), [commit 250bea0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/250bea0c1652ad546cd0455852bd734e4820ec46), [commit 3e3f347](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e3f34781964c225ca199ac50527f3ce6feddb84) (28 Jan 2019), [commit 4f732e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f732e0fd7a524759424c817b92848949db1e2db) (29 Jan 2019), and [commit 4261775](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42617752d4b22d616e276528ba4d155e6fff1835) (08 Dec 2018) by [Anders Waldenborg (`wanders`)](https://github.com/wanders).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 42977bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42977bf5c7306e4c2dded5353f39cf087cf23a1f), 07 Mar 2019)</sup>

> ### `pretty`: add support for `separator` option in `%(trailers)`

> By default trailer lines are terminated by linebreaks ('`\n`').
> By specifying the new '`separator`' option they will instead be separated by
> user provided string and have separator semantics rather than terminator
> semantics.
> The separator string can contain the literal formatting codes `%n` and `%xNN` allowing it to be things that are otherwise hard to type such as `%x00`, or comma and end-parenthesis which would break parsing.
>
> E.g:
>
> ```
> $ git log --pretty='%(trailers:key=Reviewed-by,valueonly,separator=%x00)'
> ```

And:

> ### `pretty`: add support for "`valueonly`" option in `%(trailers)`

> With the new "`key=`" option to `%(trailers)` it often makes little sense to show the key, as it by definition already is knows which trailer is
> printed there.
> This new "`valueonly`" option makes it omit the key when printing trailers.
>
> E.g.:
>
> ```
> $ git show -s --pretty='%s%n%(trailers:key=Signed-off-by,valueonly)' aaaa881
> ```
>
> will show:
>
> ```
> upload-pack: fix broken if/else chain in config callback
> Jeff King <peff@peff.net>
> Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
> ```

---

The parser for "[`git for-each-ref --format=...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e17723842b4fd42215ebf9c7ee5ab0bdfbe5a402/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L47)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---formatltformatgt))</sup>" was too loose when parsing the "`%(trailers...)`" atom, and forgot that "`trailers`" and "`trailers:<modifiers>`" are the only two allowed forms, which has been corrected with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020).

See [commit 2c22e10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c22e102f8cae598061be509344c6fdaf99c7db7), [commit a8e0f50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8e0f50edc8c4203834587541eed842497e83287) (21 Aug 2020) by [Hariom Verma (`harry-hov`)](https://github.com/harry-hov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e177238](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e17723842b4fd42215ebf9c7ee5ab0bdfbe5a402), 31 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c22e102f8cae598061be509344c6fdaf99c7db7): '`contents:trailers`' show error if `:` is missing
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Heba Waly</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Hariom Verma</sup>

> The 'contents' atom does not show any error if used with '`trailers`' atom and colon is missing before trailers arguments.
>
> e.g `%(contents:trailersonly)` works, while it shouldn't.
>
> It is definitely not an expected behavior.
>
> Let's fix this bug.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), the "`--format=%(trailers)`" mechanism gets enhanced to make it easier to design output for machine consumption.

See [commit 058761f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/058761f1c19b58afd6906672fc013327eb2096c6), [commit 9d87d5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d87d5ae026433a2993fdb757fc80dbdcb078310), [commit 8b966a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b966a0506f8b5aef7c6038fe518db45bc4a1852), [commit 2762e17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2762e17117fdd7ab73eb3f2970620a6f91500d01) (09 Dec 2020), and [commit 7c1f79f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c1f79fc16115cc971de571e4203ca78984352a7) (06 Dec 2020) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b62bbd3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b62bbd358025b39d0524a37a55bba47811128f6f), 06 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pretty format %(trailers)`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d87d5ae026433a2993fdb757fc80dbdcb078310): add a "keyonly"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Add support for a "keyonly". This allows for easier parsing out of the key and value. Before if you didn't want to make assumptions about how the key was formatted. You'd need to parse it out as e.g.:
>
> ```
> --pretty=format:'%H%x00%(trailers:separator=%x00%x00)' \
>                    '%x00%(trailers:separator=%x00%x00,valueonly)'
> ```
>
> And then proceed to deduce keys by looking at those two and subtracting the value plus the hardcoded ": " separator from the non-valueonly %(trailers) line. Now it's possible to simply do:
>
> ```
> --pretty=format:'%H%x00%(trailers:separator=%x00%x00,keyonly)' \
>                 '%x00%(trailers:separator=%x00%x00,valueonly)'
> ```
>
> Which at least reduces it to a state machine where you get N keys and correlate them with N values. Even better would be to have a way to change the ": " delimiter to something easily machine-readable (a key might contain ": " too). A follow-up change will add support for that.
>
> I don't really have a use-case for just "keyonly" myself. I suppose it would be useful in some cases as "key=*" matches case-insensitively, so a plain "keyonly" will give you the variants of the keys you matched. I'm mainly adding it to fix the inconsistency with "valueonly".

`pretty-formats` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d87d5ae026433a2993fdb757fc80dbdcb078310/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L285-L286):

> - '`keyonly[=<BOOL>]`': only show the key part of the trailer.
> - '`valueonly[=<BOOL>]`': only show the value part of the trailer.

And:

See [commit 058761f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/058761f1c19b58afd6906672fc013327eb2096c6), [commit 9d87d5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d87d5ae026433a2993fdb757fc80dbdcb078310), [commit 8b966a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b966a0506f8b5aef7c6038fe518db45bc4a1852), [commit 2762e17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2762e17117fdd7ab73eb3f2970620a6f91500d01) (09 Dec 2020), and [commit 7c1f79f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c1f79fc16115cc971de571e4203ca78984352a7) (06 Dec 2020) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b62bbd3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b62bbd358025b39d0524a37a55bba47811128f6f), 06 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pretty format %(trailers)`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/058761f1c19b58afd6906672fc013327eb2096c6): add a `"key_value_separator"`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Add a `"key_value_separator"` option to the `"%(trailers)"` pretty format, to go along with the existing "separator" argument.
> In combination these two options make it trivial to produce machine-readable (e.g. `\0` and `\0\0`-delimited) format output.
>
> As elaborated on in a previous commit which added "`keyonly`" it was needlessly tedious to extract structured data from "`%(trailers)`" before the addition of this `"key_value_separator"` option.
> As seen by the test being added here extracting this data now becomes trivial.

`pretty-formats` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/058761f1c19b58afd6906672fc013327eb2096c6/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L287-L290):

> - '`key_value_separator=<SEP>`': specify a separator inserted between
>   trailer lines. When this option is not given each trailer key-value
>   pair is separated by ": ".
>   Otherwise it shares the same semantics as '`separator=<SEP>`' above.

---

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), doc update.

See [commit b46dd17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b46dd1726c139c930d7b4b7c3262e3f2699987d3) (30 Aug 2022) by [Christian Couder (`chriscool`)](https://github.com/chriscool).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 00b0199](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00b0199c51fb6168cb219d9d4dc51d3692f72da9), 09 Sep 2022)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b46dd1726c139c930d7b4b7c3262e3f2699987d3): clarify whitespace rules for trailers
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> Commit [e431956](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4319562bc2834096fade432fd90c985b96476db) ("`trailer`: be stricter in parsing separators", 2016-11-02, Git v2.12.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b0db484e11aa86e6b8bf4d7243d0c81bf4b3c33) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6610af872f6494a061780ec738c8713a034b848b)) restricted whitespaces allowed by [`git interpret-trailers`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b46dd1726c139c930d7b4b7c3262e3f2699987d3/Documentation/git-interpret-trailers.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers))</sup> in the "token" part of the trailers it reads.
>
> Also [commit 60ef86a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60ef86a16268bfb1efb28bcb3f1b646bfad1931c) ("`trailer`: support values folded to multiple lines", 2016-10-21, Git v2.11.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cabb79d8c1c5e4f81f3435603f17c74480888395)) updated the documentation, but didn't make it clear how many whitespace characters are allowed at the beginning of new lines in folded values.

`git interpret-trailers` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b46dd1726c139c930d7b4b7c3262e3f2699987d3/Documentation/git-interpret-trailers.txt#L63-L68):

> When reading trailers, there can be no whitespace before or inside the
> token, but any number of regular space and tab characters are allowed
> between the token and the separator.
>
> There can be whitespaces before,
> inside or after the value.
>
> The value may be split over multiple lines
> with each subsequent line starting with at least one whitespace, like
> the "folding" in RFC 822.

---

When "[`git commit --trailer=...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d5c5a05d7abd67f8b667c888fe17783e1d676a5/Documentation/git-commit.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup>  invokes the interpret-trailers machinery, it knows what it feeds to interpret-trailers is a full log message without any patch, but failed to express that by passing the "`--no-divider`" option: that has been corrected with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

See [commit be3d654](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be3d65434323f7f00a5abed6dbcfe690cde648b8) (17 Jun 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8d5c5a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d5c5a05d7abd67f8b667c888fe17783e1d676a5), 26 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be3d65434323f7f00a5abed6dbcfe690cde648b8): pass `--no-divider` to interpret-trailers
>
> <sup>Reported-by: eric.frederich@siemens.com</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When [`git-commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/be3d65434323f7f00a5abed6dbcfe690cde648b8/Documentation/git-commit.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup> sees any `--trailer` options, it passes the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file through git-interpret-trailers.
> But it does so without passing `--no-divider`, which means that interpret-trailers will look for a "`---`" divider to signal the end of the commit message.
>
> That behavior doesn't make any sense in this context; we know we have a complete and solitary commit message, not something we have to further parse.
> And as a result, we'll do the wrong thing if the commit message contains a "`---`" marker (which otherwise is not syntactically significant), inserting any new trailers at the wrong spot.
>
> We can fix this by passing `--no-divider`.
>
> This is the exact situation for which it was added in [1688c9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1688c9a4894df517241026c7a3848bdc84607986) (`interpret-trailers`: allow suppressing , 2018-08-22, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fba9654364a523bf146df26052ab05dd52c1d719) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d3b1c576c85b7f5db1f418907af00ab88e0c303)) (interpret-trailers: allow suppressing "`---`" divider, 2018-08-22).
> As noted in the message for that commit, it just adds the mechanism, and further patches were needed to trigger it from various callers.
> We did that back then in a few spots, like [ffce7f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffce7f590fabee6f2314ffd891f1fd3629222839) (`sequencer`: ignore , 2018-08-22, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fba9654364a523bf146df26052ab05dd52c1d719) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d3b1c576c85b7f5db1f418907af00ab88e0c303)) (sequencer: ignore "`---`" divider when parsing trailers, 2018-08-22), but obviously missed this one.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer! The issue I'm having is trailers do not seem to work no matter what I do, it always shows me the entire body. I guess I might also be confused as to what a "trailer" is sourcing from. Is it the %s value that precedes it?  Such as %b%(trailers:...) would perform the trailer on the body?

Comment: @Brain2000 What version of Git are you using? Can you post a separate question with an example of a full commit message from which you are trying to extract trailers?

Comment: This is an amazingly thorough answer. Thanks!

Comment: @larsks Thank you. Your last post (https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2021-02-27-git-doc-tools/) is intriguing. Did you use `git dot`-generated diagrams in your answers on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I haven't yet, but I just hacked together the tool last week.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git log --invert-grep --grep="Signed-off-By"` in Git 2.4 and above. (The `--invert-grep` option was added in 2.4.)

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --show-signature
git show --show-signature
```

> --show-signature
>
> Check the validity of a signed commit object by passing the signature to gpg --verify and show the output.

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with the topic of the question (which is asking about the `signed-off-by` pseudo-header added to commit messages in some projects).