# What to put into ~/.gitconfig to imply --show-signature for every git subcommand that supports it?

Tags: git, logging, digital-signature, gnupg

I just searched through the [`git-config(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), [`git-log(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and [`git-show(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) man pages of git 2.6.2, but haven't found any hint that the `--show-signature` option (to e.g. `git show` or `git log`) can be configured globally in my `~/.gitconfig` for all `git` subcommands that support it.

One option would be aliases, but since I don't know which subcommands all support it, that's just a workaround, not a solution.

I guessed it may be `core.show-signature = yes` or `core.showSignature = yes` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: I have edited my answer: with Git 2.9.1, that would be: `git config log.showSignature true`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I confirm that this `--show-signature` option (initially introduced in [commit 0c37f1f, Oct 2011, Git v1.7.9-rc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c37f1fce6cb7997dbb2703d35eef0dfd86c5070)) <del>has no config setting or environment variable</del>.

As illustrated by [commit f2fef7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2fef7b55aea64104a6aee662817e1e6f0b22f71), that option is part of the "pretty options" [`Documentation/pretty-options.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f2fef7b55aea64104a6aee662817e1e6f0b22f71/Documentation/pretty-options.txt), which [are supported by](https://github.com/git/git/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pretty-options.txt):

- [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)
- [`git diff-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree)
- [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)
- [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

---

Update July 2016 (8 months later), with Git 2.10 (Q3 2016): "`git log`" learns `log.showSignature` configuration variable, and a command line option "`--no-show-signature`" to countermand it.

See [commit fce04c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fce04c3ca695d32c1b3c59e1bfc1fb4019025c72), [commit aa37999](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa3799996c310da756c7845950def4f6d51cccf3) (22 Jun 2016), [commit aa37999](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa3799996c310da756c7845950def4f6d51cccf3) (22 Jun 2016), and [commit aefc81a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aefc81ad38b3a6fc88a0e8db6fafe75692f0d4b3) (24 Jun 2016) by [Mehul Jain (`mehul2029`)](https://github.com/mehul2029).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 369dc40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/369dc4081c836bc17ee1debaf6688eb098359760), 11 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `log`: add `log.showSignature` configuration variable
>
> Users may want to always use "`--show-signature`" while using `git-log` and
>   related commands.
>
> When `log.showSignature` is set to true, `git-log` and related commands will behave as if "`--show-signature`" was given to them.
>
> Note that this config variable is meant to affect `git-log`, `git-show`,
>   `git-whatchanged` and `git-reflog`.
>   Other commands like `git-format-patch`, `git-rev-list` are not to be affected by this config variable.

---

Update May 2017 (11 more months later)

The [`git config` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ba4dce784e4db4c00c5d54bb22c239080049b3ee/Documentation/config.txt#L2060-L2062) is now clearer:

```
log.showSignature
```

> If `true`, makes `git-log`, `git-show`, and `git-whatchanged` assume `--show-signature`.