# Get GIT trailer value and save as variable?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I'm having some trouble figuring out GIT trailers. I'm trying to find a way to get the latest commit message, parse the trailers and and save the values from the trailers to different variables for a CI script.

I.E. the commit message would be:

```
Updated level 2 geometry

Level: Assets\LevelTwo.fbx

Platform: Android
```

And the CI system would run something like:

```
level = git interpret-trailers --parse(Level(value))
platform = git interpret-trailers --parse(Platform(value))
ReImport $level $platform
```

I'm not finding the interpret-trailers documentation very helpful in this regard as all the examples are about setting up rules to update or add trailers, and less how to get useful information out of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a random commit message,

```
1st block
blank
2nd block
blank
last block
```

The 1st block is its `subject`, which could have one or more non-blank lines. The blank block could also have one or more blank lines. The content below the 1st blank is the `body` of the message. The last block whose lines are in the format `key:value` is the trailers.

In your example,

```
Updated level 2 geometry

Level: Assets\LevelTwo.fbx

Platform: Android
```

`Updated level 2 geometry` is the subject, and the rest is the body. `Platform: Android` belongs to the trailers, while `Level: Assets\LevelTwo.fbx` does not because it's not included in the last non-blank block.

In the command `git interpret-trailers --parse <file>`, the file could be a file existing on the disk or the standard output of the previous command. The file content is supposed to be a commit message or a patch, like the output of `git log -1 --pretty='%B'` or `git format-patch -1 --stdout`.

For example we can retrieve the trailers of a commit message by

```
git log -1 $commit --pretty='%B' | git interpret-trailers --parse

# or
git format-patch -1 $commit --stdout | git interpret-trailers --parse
```

We can also dump the output to a file and then parse the file.

```
git log -1 $commit --pretty='%B' > message.txt
git interpret-trailers --parse message.txt

# or
git format-patch -1 $commit
git interpret-trailers --parse 0001-*.patch
```

I can't tell what language your CI system uses. The statements seem a bit different from git commands.

If a commit object and its sha1 value are available, we could also use placeholders `%(trailers)` to retrieve the trailers.

```
git log -1 $commit --pretty='%(trailers:key=Platform,valueonly)'
```

It returns the value of the key `Platform`, which is `Android`. `%(trailers)` prints all keys and values. `key=Platform` returns `Platform`'s key and value only. `valueonly` or `valueonly=true` returns `Platform`'s value only.

Note that `Level: Assets\LevelTwo.fbx` does not belong to the trailers. For all I know, `git interpret-trailers` or the placeholder `%(trailers)` can't directly retrieve it from the commit message. Maybe there are some options I don't know yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check if pretty format options, [acquired in Git 2.22 (Q2 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41361273/6309), could help in your case.

Example:

```
git show -s --pretty='%s%n%(trailers:key=Signed-off-by,valueonly)' aaaa881
```