# git checkout commit with specific trailer

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-log, git-show, git-switch

I have an orphan branch (let's call it output) which contains the documents generated by templates stored on my main branch. I would like to checkout the commit on output that correspond to a specific commit on main.

I settled on using `git commit --trailer 'Source: xxxxx'` when committing on output where `xxxxx` is the corresponding commit on main.

Is it possible to checkout a commit on output knowing only the value of its trailer?

Comment: "orphan branch" is not a very well defined term in Git; I presume here (and so did phd, in his answer, I think) that you mean "a branch with no shared history". (ElpieKay didn't make this same leap.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure to match a commit with a [*trailer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41361273/6309) (and not just a commit message whose topic happens to include `Source: xxxxx`), you can use [the "`%(trailers[:options])`" format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emtrailersoptionsem).
And use `git switch` ([not `checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)), or `git show` to just see the content (without modifying the current working tree)

```
git switch \
$(git log --pretty=format:"%H% (trailers:key=Source,valueonly)"|grep Junio|head -1|cut -d " " -f1)
```

Comment: This seems to offer more guarantees than @phd's answer. Just to confirm what would happen if by any chance git log was to return more than one commit?

Comment: @ITChap The `head -1` part would pick the first one (which would be the most recent one)

Answer (score 2):

To find the sha1 value of a commit that has the trailer `Source: xxxxx`,

```
git log --pretty=%H --grep='Source: xxxxx'
```

To check out the commit in one step,

```
git checkout $(git log --pretty=%H --grep='Source: xxxxx')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git show ':/Source: xxxxx'
```

See the docs on [`:/`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emlttextgtemegemfixnastybugem) in `git help revisions`.

Comment: If I understand correctly this will always return only one commit right?

Comment: @ITChap Yes. The docs clearly says "*This name returns the youngest matching commit…*"