# How to track pull-requests and merges on github repository?

Tags: git, github

I have attempted to use the Github API located here:
https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files

I am receiving a quite large json object. Because I am on an enterprise github network I am the only one authorized to merge on the repo on my account but others are allowed to fork and create pull requests. The json object does say who is submitting the pull request, however I am not sure if the json specifies who APPROVES the merge. As in although JaneDoe made the pull request, JimBob actually approves/merges it. Does the API give this information? I am unable to tell if this is present.

Answer (score 0):

I think that kind of information would be used in comments. The git tool uses the method of `--signoff` to designate approval. Perhaps if commiters would use that flag it would show up in the commit message. You could then filter the body of the commit message for the key words `Signed-off-by:` I believe.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962094/what-is-the-sign-off-feature-in-git-for) for more details.