# How to add signed off for git commit?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

The git commits made in Visual Studio 2017's team explorer does not include Signed-off-by line, and I didn't find a way to turn it on. How do I add the line in VS? On the contrary, in the thin vscode, it gives you four options, and it include everything you need:

1. Commit All
2. Commit All (Signed Off)
3. Commit Staged
4. Commit Staged (Signed Off)

But in the fat VS there is no such option?

vs2017:
[image: vs2017]
vscode:
[image: vscode]

Comment: If it's not provided, do it in the command line. Add `-s` when `git commit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cannot find a way to add the option to Team Explorer, maybe you need to write an extension to do that.

Based on the discussion in this thread [What is the Sign Off feature in Git for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962094/what-is-the-sign-off-feature-in-git-for). As my understanding the Commit with (Signed Off) is not necessary within the internal team in TFS.

> It is used to say that you certify that you have created the patch in
>   question, or that you certify that to the best of your knowledge, it
>   was created under an appropriate open-source license, or that it has
>   been provided to you by someone else under those terms. This can help
>   establish a chain of people who take responsibility for the copyright
>   status of the code in question, to help ensure that copyrighted code
>   not released under an appropriate free software (open source) license
>   is not included in the kernel.

However, if you want to use it, just as ElpieKay said, you can do it in the command line.

```
-s
--signoff
Add Signed-off-by line by the committer at the end of the commit log message.
```

When you commit, just use:

```
git commit -s
```

or

```
git commit --signoff
```

Refer to this link for details: http://schacon.github.io/git/git-commit.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, I didn't find any other way to do it in VS.