# How to ask for CLA signature in merge requests on GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I would like to publish a project under GPL license, but would like to request CLA (Contributor License Agreements) signing before accepting merge requests.

GitHub has a few solutions which automate this ([ClaHub](https://www.clahub.com/), [cla-assistant](https://github.com/cla-assistant/cla-assistant)), however I can't find anything similar for GitLab. There is a [long standing issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22103) to add support for it natively, but it's been opened 2 years ago.

I know [Git sign-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962094/what-is-the-sign-off-feature-in-git-for) can be used for DCO, but I am wondering if it could somehow be (ab)used for signing CLA agreements?

In short, how do I make the process of signing CLAs as painless as possible for both contributors and myself, while still making the agreements (somewhat) legally binding?

**EDIT:** To the person who cast a vote for closing: I checked the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and it seems to me that the question falls squarely in `software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`. It also doesn't fall into exceptions listed, at least the way I understand them. That said, I would appreciate a comment about the reasons for the vote, so that I can formulate the question better or find a more suitable StackExchange site if needed.

Comment: Ahhh, "painless" and "legally" in the same sentence. Must be a trick question :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I assure you it is not, I am genuinly interested in the answer... ;) I am sure it will be a compromise though.

Comment: I'm curious too. It's actually interesting that this isn't something that's made it to GitHub already.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not sure if that was just a typo, but just to be clear: I am specifically asking for Git*Lab*, as Git*Hub* has this issue (long) solved.

Comment: It'sa typo caused by autocorrect.

Comment: The feature request for this now appears to be [CLA support (#15899)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/22103).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no official native support for CLA in GitLab for now.
The issue you are referencing is linked to [issue 48118 ("Stakeholder approval for merge requests")](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/48118), but itself is linked to two GitLab *Enterprise* issues -[issues 1979 "Multiple blocking merge request approval rules"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/1979) and [issue 965 "Upgrading approvals with approval chain"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/965))

So for now, relying on a third-party service site remains the "less painful" solution.
That means, using the services highlighted in the original issue: [CLAClub](https://www.clahub.com/) or [cla-assistant.io](https://cla-assistant.io/).

The last one (cla-assistant) will, for a public registered repo (registered to cla-assistant) will:

- Comments on each opened pull request to ask the contributor to sign the CLA
- Allows contributors to sign a CLA from within a pull request
- Authenticates the signee with his or her GitHub account
- Updates the status of a pull request when the contributor agrees to the CLA
- Automatically asks users to re-sign the CLA for each new pull request in the event the associated Gist & CLA has changed

Note: you can install and run your own instance of cla-assistant in order to store in your own private dedicated database the CLAs for your project.

But: since those services are tied to *GitHub* accounts, and there is no equivalent for GitLab, DCO should not be dismissed, especially in light of the Nov. 2017 GitLab blog post "[GitLab Transitions Contributor Licensing to Developer Certificate of Origin to Better Support Open Source Projects; Empower Contributors](https://about.gitlab.com/press/releases/2017-11-01-gitlab-transitions-contributor-license.html) "

> GitLab’s move away from a CLA is meant to modernize its code hosting and collaborative development infrastructure for all open source projects.
>
> Additionally, requiring a CLA became problematic for developers who didn’t want to enter into legal terms; they weren’t reviewing the CLA contract and they effectively gave up their rights to own and contribute to open source code.

And "[We're switching to a DCO for source code contributions](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/11/01/gitlab-switches-to-dco-license/)". When it comes to GitLab projects, a [DCO like this one](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/dco) remains the chosen solution.
See the [analysis comparing CLA and DCO](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zpjDzL7yhGBZz3_7jCjWLfRQ1Jryg1mlIVmG8y6B1_Q/edit).

---

[GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#enforce-developer-certificate-of-origin-on-all-contributions) (October 2022) prpose for non-free editions of GitLab:

> ### Enforce Developer Certificate of Origin on all contributions
>
> The Developer Certificate of Origin (DCO) is a per-commit sign-off made by a contributor stating that they have the right to submit the code to the project. By signing off on a commit, the contributor agrees to the terms published at [developercertificate.org](https://developercertificate.org).
>
> Now, you can easily enforce this Developer Certificate via [a per-project setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/push_rules.html#reject-commits-that-arent-dco-certified) to prevent contributors from contributing code that violates your license. When enabled, all new commits must include such a certificate of origin in the form of a line in the commit message `Signed-off-by:`.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_5/enforce_dco_all_contributions.png -- Enforce Developer Certificate of Origin on all contributions]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/push_rules.html#reject-commits-that-arent-dco-certified) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/368894).

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean when you say "relying on a third-party service site"? Can you maybe outline how the workflow would look like?

Comment: @johndodo I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, this workflow is then tied to contributors having a GitHub account?

Comment: @johndodo Yes: there is no equivalent service using GitLab account for now (https://forum.gitlab.com/t/contributor-cla-checker/9626/2). You can see another approach in https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/7487#issuecomment-342347189.

Comment: @johndodo I have edited the answer to contrast CLA with the DCO you were mentionning in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort! Unfortunately DCO is not a suitable solution for my use case (I would like to have an open-core model), but it might help someone else with the same problem. I am a bit torn - the answer is full of bits of interesting information, but I knew most of it already, and it doesn't actually suggest a way for contributors to sign the CLA for GitLab-hosted project... So let's wait if someone else has any suggestion, otherwise I'll accept your answer (and probably move the project to GitHub, much as I don't like doing it). I do appreciate the effort though!

Comment: @johndodo I understand. The point is: GitLab does not seem encline to use/consider CLAs. Hence its switch to DCO. So I would be surprised if there is any equivalent of CLA-based support *for GitLab projects*.